# view sql generated by WSO2 DSS service

Tags: oracle, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We have a very large SQL statement in our WSO2 DSS service which is executing a query against an Oracle database. With some parameters the query works. With others it fails and the Oracle error indicates there is a missing right ")" in the SQL statement. How can we see the actual SQL being sent to Oracle when the DSS executes. We've tried enabling DEBUG on any relevant looking logger and no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn debug level in you DSS/Configure/Logging for
org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery
Then in Monitor/System Logs - you can see queries that was called and it's exceptions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [log4jdbc](https://github.com/arthurblake/log4jdbc) to log every jdbc query that goes from DSS to Oracle. [Here is a tutorial](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/07/how-to-use-log4jdbc-with-wso2-products_28.html) you can follow.